# Azure C# v2 Function: Inconsistent accessibility for function parameter

Tags: c#, azure

I am building a C# Azure v2 timer function app with two functions: a timer function that runs every set period of time to read data from an Azure Table Storage (`RunAsync`) and another function that is used to copy the read data into another Table Storage (`CopyRows`). However, I receive the following error in the definition of the `CopyRows` function:

> Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type
> `'TableQuery<RoleAssignment>'` is less accessible than method
> `'Function1.CopyRows(TableQuery<RoleAssignment>, string)'`

Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Buffers.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace AccessChangeMonitoring
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        // Function that reads a small portion of the role assignments table (OneAuthZRoleAssignments) every 
        // configurable number of times
        public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("%TimerTriggerPeriod%")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
        }

        [FunctionName("CopyRows")]
        // Copies a list of rows to another table 
        public static void CopyRows(TableQuery<RoleAssignment> queriedRows, string nameOfDestinationTable)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `RoleAssignment` class. It is probably marked as `internal` or `private`. Change it to `public` and everything should work.

The reason is that you can't have a public method (`CopyRows`) which points to an `internal` class.

Comment: Unlikely it's `private` since you cannot declare top-level `private` classes and unless it's defined inside of `Function1` (which not shown in the OP) then it wouldn't be accessible and would generate a different error (CS0246)